# what is the meaning of this TregexPattern

Tags: regex, nlp, stanford-nlp

```
TregexPattern pattern = TregexPattern.compile**("@NP < (__ $ __) !<< (@NP < (__ $ __)) !<< @PP")**;
```

Comment: Just read https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html

Comment: i have already read it ; but i didn't understand this pattern

Answer (score 1):

A noun phrase with at least two children which doesn't contain a noun phrase with at least two children nor a prepositional phrase.  E.g. (NP (DT the) (NN car)).